# What does Amazon S3 use the content type header for?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

So I've got a python web app that takes images uploaded by users and shoves them into S3 for storage using boto3 like so:

```
s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, filename).put(Body=file_obj.read(), ContentType="image/*")
```

I was under the impression that you needed to specify the correct content type (i.e image/jpeg, image/bmp, etc) when uploading or else S3 will not handle the files correctly, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I tested it with a content type of "image/*" and with no content type at all and everything seems to be working fine - images upload and store fine, and when re-downloaded they aren't corrupted or anything.

The only difference I see so far is that without the content type your web browser will download the file instead of displaying the image in a new tab (when using the S3 management console)

Is this conclusion correct? That the content type only dictates how browsers handle the file in question, or does S3 use it for something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

S3 doesn't use `Content-Type` for anything.

The user agent (browser) is -- as you noticed -- where that information needs to be available (and correct).

There are several others that are similar, like `Content-Encoding`, `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, and `Content-Disposition` -- S3 just returns these with the response when the object is fetched, for the browser's benefit.  These don't change S3 behavior.

There's also an [interesting capability for `GET` requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) using pre-signed URLs, where you can ask S3 to override the stored value and return something different in the response.  A *signed* URL with `response-content-type=application/octet-stream` in the query string would trigger S3 to return `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` for that single response, regardless of what you had stored in S3.

Only `x-amz-*` headers, *excluding* those matching `x-amz-meta-*` will actually cause behavior variations with S3, such as `x-amz-acl` and `x-amz-storage-class`.

---

There are a couple of other headers that break this general pattern, and are perhaps worth separate mention:

`X-Robots-Tag` seems completely undocumented, but is also accepted on uploads and returned to the browser with each `GET`, so the behavior here is much like `Content-Type` and friends, mentioned above.  S3 takes no action based on it.  This header is for signaling well-behaved crawlers, similar to `/robots.txt`. A common value is `X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow` (don't index this page, don't follow links on this page).  This header is returned with each download, but can only be set via the API. It's visible in the console, but can't be set or edited with the console.  It's a bit of a stealth feature, completely undocumented as far as I know.

`Content-MD5` is an optional (but highly recommended) request header sent with uploads.  It contains the binary md5 of the request body, encoded in base64.  This header is *not* returned when you fetch an object, but is used to verify that an upload has not been corrupted.  If the the request body doesn't match this hash, the upload is rejected with an erroe by S3, and never saved.